# Does it matter how long I stay at the strip club with a friend?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Sometimes when hanging out with friends, like Brucie and Jacob, I take them to the strip club. However, I'm rather impatient with the whole standing around a strip club doing nothing thing so I only wait a few seconds and then find my partner to leave. When I do that, they always comment that they weren't in there very long, yada yada.

I'm wondering, does the amount of time I actually spend in the strip club matter, or affect how much my Like % will go up for that person? Or does it only matter that you actually went in?

Comment: "However, I'm rather impatient with the whole standing around a strip club doing nothing thing so I only wait a few seconds and then find my partner to leave."  You are doing it wrong, my friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It only matters that you actually went in.** Unlike other activities in GTA IV, there is nothing at a strip club that you and a friend engage in together to increase the like %. Such as, when you go bowling, you have to bowl. If you go throw darts you have to actually throw a round of darts. etc.

Getting a lap dance is an available activity at a strip club, but according to [the GTA4 wiki:](http://www.grandtheftwiki.com/Friendships_in_GTA_IV)

> Visit a strip club. There are The Triangle Club in Northern Gardens (Bohan), and Honkers Gentlemen's Club in Tudor (Alderney). Lapdances are available in strip clubs but are not mandatory in order to complete the visit.

So, next time Roman calls you up to see some "Big American Tee-Tees" you can just humor him quickly and leave.